# Where can I download "Expedition to the Ancient Academy" podcast episodes?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, odnd, podcast

I want to listen to the following podcast featuring early edition D&D:

http://robertsongames.com/dnd/robertson-games-podcast

But I can't find the actual audio files anywhere.  The podcast is in iTunes, but they only have the last two episodes of that series there.

Help! Where can I get the audio for this from?

Answer (score 3):

Episodes 5, 6 and 7 are here: http://rpggeek.com/rpgpodcast/7082/robertson-games

According to various blog posts in late 2011, the "first half" of the series is not available for sharing.

PS the free one-page dungeon is here: http://www.lulu.com/shop/robertson-games/the-ancient-academy/ebook/product-4860255.html